# create docker file for postgresql and golang

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I have project that uses Go and postgresql

What is the optimal solution for creating a DockerFile?

use os[for example ubuntu] in docker and install go and postgresql? or
use those separately[use go and postgresql and connection between them]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker suggest one container for one task, you could refers to [Multi container apps](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/):

> We have been working with single container apps. But, we now want to add MySQL to the application stack. The following question often arises - “Where will MySQL run? Install it in the same container or run it separately?” In general, **each container should do one thing and do it well**. A few reasons:
>
> - There’s a good chance you’d have to scale APIs and front-ends differently than databases
> - Separate containers let you version and update versions in isolation
> - While you may use a container for the database locally, you may want to use a managed service for the database in production. You don’t want to ship your database engine with your app then.
> - Running multiple processes will require a process manager (the container only starts one process), which adds complexity to container startup/shutdown
>
> And there are more reasons. So, we will update our application to work like this:
>
> [image]

So, for you, you should choose `use go and postgresql in different containers and connection between them`.